# Convergence of Sequence of arithmetic mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $a_{n+2}=\frac {a_{n+1}+a_{n}}{2}$  $\forall n$>0 ,I have to show that $a_{n}\to \frac {a_{1}+2a_{2}}{3}$.
I don't know this problem is easy or difficult as intially I was posting here my query about question but at the time of writting problem I got this solution .If any mistake please tell me ..

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039868/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472784/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859005/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702193/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to show existence of limit We have term $a_1,a_2$ we know that given seunce is of artihematice mean or we also show that min{$a_1,a_2$} 
 < a3 < max{$a_1,a_2$}
 WLOG say $a_1 < a_3 < a_2$ 
 Similarly to above we can say that $a_3 < a_4 < a_2$  And by induction we can easily show that given sequence is monotonic and bounded above so Must be convergent to say a.
 $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$=$\frac {a_{n}-a_{n+1}}{2}$ 
Taking Sum for index n we get as this alternating series 
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i+2}-a_{+1}$=$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {a_{i}-a_{i+1}}{2}$
So we left with $a_{n+2}-a_{2}$=$\frac {a_{1}-a_{n+1}}{2}$ By Transferring We left with what is needed $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}/2$=$\frac {a_{1}+2a_{2}}{2}$ 
 As $a_n \to a$ So 3$a_n$/2=$\frac {a_{1}+2a_{2}}{2}$ Which leads to required solution.

Answer (score 1):

Write $b=(a_1+2a_2)/3$ and $c=a_1-b$. Then $a_2-b=(-1/2)c$, $a_3-b=(1/4)c$
and in general $a_n-b=(-1/2)^{n-1}c$. So $a_n\to b$.

Comment: Nice answer But Sir is there in short method other than mentioned to find limit also because here you are assuming that is limit and then showing convergence. i.e what if we do not know Limit ?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider
$$a_{n+2}=\frac {a_{n+1}+a_{n}}{2}$$ the characteristic equation is $r^2=\frac{r+1}2$, the roots of which being $r_1=-\frac 12$ and $r_2=1$. So, the genaral solution is
$$a_n=c_1 \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+c_2$$ If we impose $a_1=A$, $a_2=B$, this leads to

$$a_n=\frac 13 \left(A+2B+(-1)^n\frac{(B-A)}{2^{n-2}} \right)$$

Comment: Sir ,What is this characteristics equation ? can you explain something please?

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation: $2\lambda^2-\lambda -1=0$ has 2 solutions: $1$ and $\frac{-1}{2}.$

Thus, $a_{n}=A+B.\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n,$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants such that $a_1=A-\frac{B}{2}, a_2=A+\frac{B}{4}.$ So, $A=\frac{a_1+2a_2}{3}.$

Moreover, $\{a_n\}$ converges to $A=\frac{a_1+2a_2}{3}.$

Comment: What is characteristics equation?

Comment: You find the method which solves linear recursive sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{-2}$$ and by induction

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_2-a_1}{(-2)^{n-1}}.$$

Then

$$a_{n}-a_1=(a_{n}-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+\cdots(a_2-a_1)\\
=(a_2-a_1)\left(1-\frac12+\frac14-\cdots\frac1{(-2)^{n-2}}\right)$$

where the summation tends to $\dfrac23$. You can draw $a_\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1=a_2=1$. The next terms are obviously $1,1,1,\cdots$.

Now let $a_1=2,a_2=-1$. The next terms are $\frac12,-\frac14,\frac18,\cdots \left(-\frac12\right)^k,\cdots$ (because $\frac{\left(-\frac12\right)^0+\left(-\frac12\right)^1}2=\left(-\frac12\right)^2$).

Now for arbitrary $a_1,a_2$, find the linear combination such that

$$p\,(1,1)+q\,(2,-1)=(a_1,a_2).$$

> From the linear system, $3p=a_1+2a_2$ and the limit is $1\,p+0\,q$.